# In Java 7, transparent GIF doesn't animate properly

Tags: animation, java-7, transparent, gif, animated

So, I'm having an issue with a program. I have a GIF that's transparent. The animation works properly, except that instead of showing one image at a time, it sort of stacks the images on top of each other. I tried overriding the paintIcon method of the ImageIcon class to clear the canvas, but that didn't work either. ANy thoughts?
My code:

```
    public class GifRunner extends JPanel {
      JLabel label;
      public GifRunner() {
        super();
        label = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/animation.gif");
        label.setIcon(icon);
        add(label);
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GifRunner panel = new GifRunner();
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you provide the GIF and what OS are you running on, please

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7, happens on both. [Here's the image](http://i1211.photobucket.com/albums/cc432/sk8torchic/normal_zpsa40697c9.gif)

Comment: Okay, turns out I was wrong about the java version somehow. It's Java 6. Does that change anything?

Comment: I can't say it would...

Comment: I'd say it's not Java, but the Gif that's at fault - or a combination of each.  Do you have a gif editor?

Comment: Just to clarify, I downloaded you Gif and got the same problem you've described. But seen as I've had other gifs work fine, I can only conclude that your gif isn't setup correctly

Answer (score 0):

you can override the ImageIcon's paintIcon function and manually clear the canvas:

```
class ClearImageIcon extends ImageIcon{

    public ClearImageIcon(String filename){super(filename);}

    @Override
    public synchronized void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        g2.clearRect(0, 0, getIconWidth(), getIconHeight());
        super.paintIcon(c, g2, x, y);
    }
}
```

it will draw every frame nicely on to the screen.

Comment: I actually tried that already, for some reason it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me...

Windows 7, Java 7.

[image]

[Original](http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2012/089/0/1/appleture_animated_gif_by_inkwell_pony-d4uggao.gif)

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class AnimatedGifTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AnimatedGifTest();
  }

  public AnimatedGifTest() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TestPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    public TestPane() {
      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\swhitehead\\Documents\\My Dropbox\\Ponies\\appleture_animated_gif_by_inkwell_pony-d4uggao.gif");
      JLabel label = new JLabel(image);
      add(label);
    }        
  }      
}
```